# AMP - how to make a link to back previous page in amp?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am using blade template of laravel.
Do we have any way to implement back function in amp page?

I tried 3 ways but all are fail:

- **a on="tap:AMP.goBack"** does not work
- **a href="javascript:history.back()"** will work but it get error from validator amp.
- **amp-script** does not support History API.

Answer (score 0):

Amp dev advise me to use: **AMP.goBack(navigate=true)**. Now it works same as **javascript:history.back()**.

Refs:

- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/26585
- https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/5225